# Split value into percentage with a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

im new to jQuery and searching a way for doing smthing like this:

I have a value [100] and 5 categorys [apple, banana, kiwi, lemon, orange]

What I want is to have for each category a slider (a line with a point on it you can move)

So every category starts with a value of 20 (100 / 5).

When there is more banana than apple and you "slide" banana to the value of 40 the other values should decrase so I've still the full percentage of 100%.

Anyone knows a plugin or has a handy snippet?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://jqueryui.it/demos/slider

Comment: This is basically the thing I'm looking for - forgive me the dumb question, but which option/event/method could I use in my case to archieve auto-adjusting?

Comment: Set up five of those sliders as you said.  Create a .slide event handler for each of them, which figures out what the value of the slider being slid is, and sets the other sliders' values to compensate.